# How to create a function with the same context as require in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, class, function, this

This question is due to an error when I try to use this on a file. I have a file with a class for the page:

```
class Page {
   function whatHappen()
   {
      echo "this may work";
   }  
   function helloWorld()
   {
       echo "This is my page!";
       require( "usethis.php" );      // --> this works
       similar_require( "usethis.php" );    // ---> with this I get an error
   }
   function write()
   {
       $this->helloWorld();
   }
}
```

And a function that similar to require:

```
function similar_require( $filepath )
{
   require( $filepath );
}
```

In usethis.php file I have this:

```
<?php
   $this->whatHappen();
?>
```

How to do work similar_require and require like the same function?

Comment: What exactly is the error? are you using both require statements at once? try commenting out the first require statement if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

In usethis.php you are trying to access `$this`, which is not declared in scope of `similar_require` function.
Read about visibility: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

All this code looks very dirty: don't use 'require' or 'include' in methods or functions - it's like using globals (and globals are very bad thing).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
function similar_require( $filepath, $this )
{
   require( $filepath );
}
```

and

```
similar_require( "usethis.php", $this );
```